# Where to find Jackson 1.x documentation

Tags: jackson

It seems that codehaus.org has shut its doors and with it, the documentation for Jackson versions 1.x is gone. Is there anywhere else I can find them?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs

Gives a link under: Older Jackson in 5 minutes version (useful for 1.x)

Here is the link: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

And finally here:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome contains older documentation (some 1.x specific; but mostly relevant for both 1.x and 2.x)